# Why must a non-dense subset of the disk contain points satisfying the following condition?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $U$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $A$ be an open non-empty subset of $U$ that is not dense in $U.$

Under these conditions, why is it then true that there exists $\alpha \in A,$ $\beta \in U - \bar{A}$ such that $$2 |\beta-\alpha| < 1-|\beta|?$$ This should be straightforward, but I can not see why at the moment.

Comment: I would start with the definition of "non-dense" or "not dense" in $U$.

Comment: In fact, the existence of such $\alpha, \beta$ does **not** follow. $A$ might be empty.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What about for A non-empty?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, that is the obvious thing, bur that gave me nothing. There is some point x that is not a limit point of A, so it is at a positive sistance from the closure of A, but I do not see why that gives me what I am after immediately.

Comment: Right, since $U-\overline A$ is open, it contains an open disk around any $\beta$ in that set.

Comment: @hardmath I am sorry, but I still do not see why this gives the claimed inequality. Would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below, closures and boundaries are taken with respect to $U.$

Because $U\setminus \bar A$ is nonempty, $\partial \bar A$ is nonempty, otherwise $A = \bar A,$ contradicting the connectivity of $U.$ Thus there exists $c\in \partial \bar A = \partial (U\setminus \bar A).$ Hence there exist sequences $a_n$ in $\bar A$ and $b_n$ in $U\setminus \bar A$ converging to $c.$ We can then find $a_n'\in A$ converging to $c.$ It follows that $|a_n'-b_n|\to 0.$ Note that $1-|b_n|\to 1-|c|>0.$ This implies

$$|a_n'-b_n| < (1-|b_n|)/2$$

for large $n.$ This gives the desired result.